# I am facing issue in second `<li>`, it's not aligned form when in mobile version is opened in browser

Tags: html, css

```
<ul class="home-ul-content">
    <li class="wrapper">
        <i id="check1" class="fa fa-check content-check"></i> <span id="content-show1" class="content-show">WE PREPARE VEGETRARIAN INDIAN FOOD</span>
    </li>
    <li class="wrapper">
        <i id="check2" class="fa fa-check content-check"></i> <span id="content-show2" class="content-show">WE OFFER COMPLETELY VEGAN AND GLUTEN FREE GERMANY FLAVORS</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The GLUTEN(text) coming below the check, it should come below the above text
[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGBD1.png)

Comment: When you were asking your question, there was a big orange **How to Format** box to the right of the text area with useful information in it. There was also an entire toolbar of formatting aids. And a **[?]** button giving formatting help. *And* a preview area located between the text area and the Post Your Question button (so that you'd have to scroll past it to find the button, to encourage you to look at it) showing what your post would look like when posted. Making your post clear, and demonstrating that you took the time to do so, improves your chances of getting good answers.

Comment: I've fixed the formatting for you on this occasion, but the question is still unclear. Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Just change the list-style-position in your css.

```
ul {
   list-style-position: outside;
}
```

That should sort out the alignment issue

Comment: could you please replicate your issue in jsfiddle?